# Running SiftGPU on OpenCV Mat

Tags: opencv, gpu, sift

I am trying to run [SiftGPU](http://cs.unc.edu/~ccwu/siftgpu/) on 'frame's grabbed in OpenCV Mat from the camera and having trouble converting Mat format to the input format taken by SiftGPU. I did not find any concrete specification on the input SiftGPU accepts (in its manual; it just says some data pointer). Anyone successfully implemented this?

Answer (score 0):

if you are still intrested, you can pass the data in like so:

```
sift.RunSIFT(mat.cols, mat.rows, mat.data, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);
```

if you dont want to add glew.h for those definition just put these lines of code

```
#define GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE 0x1401
#define GL_BGR 0x80E0
#define GL_BGRA 0x80E1
#define GL_RGB 0x1907
#define GL_RGBA 0x1908
```

Answer (score 0):

I can share my code for you like this:

```
cv::Mat myMat = imread("../data/800-4.jpg");
int width = myMat.cols;
int height = myMat.rows;
unsigned char *data = (uchar*)myMat.data;//GL_RGBA
sift->RunSIFT(width, height, data, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);
```